Capacitor Insulation Questions
I wanted to create a high voltage parallel plate capacitor with a positive voltage connected to its positive plate and ground connected to its negative plate.
Can I get away with a thin sheet of insulation on the bottom while using dielectric sheets with sufficient dielectric breakdown strength for the top and middle dielectrics?
For example, say 1000 Volts was connected to the positive plate. Can I get away with using dielectrics with a breakdown strength of greater than 1000 Volts for the top and middle dielectric sheets but use a dielectric sheet of minimal strength on the bottom since the negative plate is just ground?

Be aware that dielectric strength refers to the magnitude of the electric field in V/m that will cause breakdown, not the absolute voltage in V.

The only dielectric you actually need is that between the plates (and the edges), and it must be capable of withstanding the 1kV you intend on applying (with some safety margin to allow for pinholes and other imperfections).
If your bottom plate is grounded it doesn't actually need any insulation.
If nothing can get near your top plate (other than the well-insulated conductor you use to connect to it) you don't need to insulate it. If it can, then the insulation will depend on the relative voltage, which could be 1kV if the object is grounded, or possibly even more (maybe you are making a voltage doubler or something like that).
If your intention is to insulate it well enough that it's safe to handle, that would require significant care and large safety  margins that should be supervised by a local expert, particularly if there is potentially harmful fault current available (like a HV supply connected to the capacitor).

Yes, you can do that, as long as your ground is actually earthed as well.
